# how do I turn a string into a directory entry?

Tags: c++, filesystems

I basically just need some simple way to convert an `std::string` into `std::filesystem::directory_entry&`. could anyone help with that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just pass a `std::string` to `std::filesystem::directory_entry`'s constructor, as long as you do it explicitly: `std::filesystem::directory_entry entry{some_string};`

Comment: `std::filesystem::directory_entry` has constructors that take a `std::filesystem::path` as input, and a `path` can be constructed from a `std::(w)string`

Comment: [directory_entry constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry/directory_entry), [path constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path). Note in particular path ctor (4).